# Catch all exceptions within a thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, loops, while-loop

Below is the code I have developed for a thread.

```
   int i;
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(true) {
                    sleep(10000);
                    i++
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

Is there any possible way I can use any other catch or exception to catch all possible crushes within it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean, like, `catch (Exception e)`?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: Well there's your answer then.

Comment: You can have an `Error` or an `Exception` (InterruptedException inherits from Exception). So if you catch those, you catch everything. That said, a `while` in itself won't throw an Exception, the `sleep` will.

Answer (score 2):

Just have `catch (Exception ex)` as well as `catch (InterruptedException e)`

Comment: With 2 try and catches?

Comment: No, you can add any number of catches to one try.

Comment: You mean like `catch (InterruptedException, Exception e)`?

Comment: } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: In general, capturing Exception is a **bad practice**, more info on this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938/is-it-really-that-bad-to-catch-a-general-exception

Answer (score 2):

It seems that only exception that block can throw,you have already handled but for safer side you can catch parent exception too i,e (Exception e) as below :

```
 try {
   //stuff
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I'll accept the first one because he said it first.

Comment: thnks @We'reAllMadHere :)

Comment: In general, capturing Exception is a **bad practice**, more info on this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938/is-it-really-that-bad-to-catch-a-general-exception

Comment: @NKN yes i knw.but it will better to dnt leave any exception without any catch.You can add the exception catch after specific exception like in this case we are handling InterruptedException which can be caused by sleep but if other exception arise thn super class exception will handle