# Declaration Of Catch For Generic Exception in java android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, androidx

During my code scanning through sonarqube. I had found these warning. **"Declaration Of Catch For Generic Exception"**

```
**} catch (Exception e) { - RelevantPart: catch**
```

If any one face same please help me :

Comment: The warning means instead of catching the base class Exception, you should catch the specific type of exception you expect to be thrown.

Comment: [Is it really that bad to catch a general exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21938/3890632)

Comment: You mean to say i need to use try{} catch (IOException e) {
logger.error("doExchange failed", e);
}

Comment: If IOException is the exception you actually need to deal with, yes, that is what the warning is about. Whether you do what it says or not is up to you.