# Passing Business Validation Error from Service layer to presentation layer

Tags: service, exception, presentation-layer

We are using MVP pattern in our Presentation Layer(PL) and a WCF based service layer(SL). PL calls operation contracts on the SL and internally it does some business validations. If the validation passes, we return an obect (exposed as a data contract) to the PL.

But if the validation fails, what is the best practice we notify the PL.

```
Entity2 Operation1(Entity1 e)
{
 //Do some business validation and if passes pass on the updated object back to PL
}
```

One way is we create a generic Response Class which is common for all operation contracts. It'll look something like this.

```
public class Response
{
    public ExceptionType exceptionType;
    public ExceptionInfo exceptionInfo;

    Collection<Entity> entityCollection;
}
```

ExceptionType: This is an enum which tells if the businessValidation failed or SecurityValidation or some unknown exception occured.

ExceptionInfo: This is an enum which tells specific details of the validation/exception occured like errorCode, etc.

Collection: The service layer can return a single entity or a collection of entity. We use this property to return the entity or entities as per requirement. It can be null also in case there was an validation failure or the method doesnt expect any return entity from the service layer.

Is this a good approach to pass on the validation failures to PL.

On drawback of this I see is - the PL needs to handle all the cases defined in exceptionInfo, probably use a switch case and do neccessary things.

Other way to do this is throw exceptions to the PL if any business validation or security validation fails. I am not much keen on this approach because i dont want to use exception to handle my business logic.

Any more ideas to handle this scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

[How Do You Communicate Service Layer Messages/Errors to Higher Layers Using MVP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21697/how-do-you-communicate-service-layer-messages-errors-to-higher-layers-using-mvp)

I'm not sure how to help specifically here.  First, I don't really understand your setup, or know anything about WCF particulars.  Second, I don't really get the comment about disliking exceptions for biz logic... but I'm assuming you mean "business validation" as you stated elsewhere (in which case, that makes sense to me).

In my ignorance, it looks like you've got the start of your own scheme going, so maybe you've got a lot of freedom.  And certainly a lot of things *could* work.  So, here are some alternatives:

### Method of Communication

You might just try your approach and see how you like it.  IMO, it's mixing concerns a little to validate and operate together (sometime it can't be helped, esp. if you start asking how to handle failures).  Command-Query, stuff aside, this is a classic return-vs-throw issue and, at this boundary, you're within rights to choose either as long as it works.

If you have a framework for your MVP, you might see if it has anything built in.

Barring that, you could change your PL/SL relationship to separate validation explicitly from the operation.  Like so:

```
IList<Error> Validate_Operation1(Entity1 a){}
Entity2 Operation1(Entity1 a){}
```

Or, to be way crazy:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    IList<Param> Params { set; }
    IList<Error> Validate();
    void Execute();
}
```

If I was firmly differentiating "Validation Errors" apart from "Post-Validation Errors" and "Unexpected Errors", I might do the above.  Getting validation problems back as a result of asking for validation certainly isn't "exceptional".

All that aside, you might consider getting a little more abstract into what you're going to do with post-validation errors.  Some of these you may be user-actionable, whether or not they're biz related.  "Datatraveler appears corrupt.  Please reformat thumbdrive."  Or even warnings like "Preferences not found, completed with defaults."  If your app is highly interactive, your chatty SL might use the more general mechanism to send back validation issues.

### Content of Communication

I don't see your Response-class-with-error-enums-and-null-entities as being miles different from defining your own error class or exception, honestly.  I'm not big on a "multi-purpose" return like this but there's a case for that approach:  Many EventArgs or async callback args are implemented to have the error, cancel, and results information.

Regarding your listed drawback, I'm not sure how broad the error hierarchy is when you say "the PL needs to handle all the cases defined in exceptionInfo", so forgive me for assuming the worst here.  The vehicle you choose (exceptions, plain strings, or an exceptionInfo enum) doesn't change the fact that, if you recognize 762 distinct errors, you recognize 762 distinct errors.

But that doesn't mean your presenters need to account for every one explicitly.  You've got the benefit of context - you know you aren't going to get "Username was blank" after the user's already logged in and is checking their mortgage balance.  (And if you do, you should probably treat that as "Unexpected error while checking balance.  Please try again later." and log the call stack, right?)

So your presenter only needs to know the shorter list that applies to its context, not all of them.  Everything else is "Unexpected ...".

And, since you're defining your own Error class, you might consider putting your errors in string resources and tying the resource ID to the specific error when you create the object.  Then, instead of individually handling the cases, many of them can be resolve by the same action:  Get ID, load string, show string, done.  No switch-statement required.